# How can I set child props when testing a React component?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have this component

```
const InputWithLabel = ({
                          id,
                          value,
                          type = 'text',
                          onInputChange,
                          isFocused,
                          children,
                        }) => {...
return(<>
        <label htmlFor={id} className="label">
                {children}
        </label>
...
</>)}
```

and I am doing testing with :

```
describe('InputWithLabel',()=>{
    const inputWithLabelProps={
        id:"search",
        value:"React",
        isFocused:true,
        onInputChange:jest.fn,
        children:[]
    }
    test('check the existence of InputWithLabel',()=>{
        render(<InputWithLabel {...inputWithLabelProps}/>);
        screen.debug();// This to see the renders of the Element 
    });
})
```

What value I can put on children:[] for do the test .
I tried with array of object but don't work. Any Ideas ?

Comment: A fragment for example `children:<></>` or any jsx

Comment: Are the children set of tags? or set of values? If you want to show them you have to loop through them. With a map function. Or put a single element or value.

Comment: Do I need to reproduce the JSX expected of these children?

Comment: This is your test, you should know what you want to test

Answer (score 0):

In my case this is the solution, this the calling of component

```
<InputWithLabel
          id="search"
          value={searchTerm}
          isFocused
          onInputChange={onSearchInput}
      >
        <strong>Search:</strong>
      </InputWithLabel>
```

and the test will be:

```
describe('InputWithLabel',()=>{
    const inputWithLabelProps={
        id:"search",
        value:"React",
        isFocused:true,
        onInputChange:jest.fn,
        children:<strong>Search:</strong>
    }
    test('check the existence of InputWithLabel',()=>{
        render(<InputWithLabel {...inputWithLabelProps}/>);
        screen.debug();
    });
})
```

pls notice

```
<strong>Search:</strong>
```

is the children of the my component